# Quick Help in Xcode - How to create links between classes in the same project

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, comments, appledoc

In a class, I have the following method and comment:

```
/**
 A list of GSDContentLayer objects comprising the layers for the current drawing.
 @see GSDContentLayer for an explanation on drawing layers.
*/
-(NSArray *)layers;
```

This comment can be seen in Quick Help in Xcode, and it works well.

I would like, however, to create a link in the second comment line pointing to GSDContentLayer, so that when I click on the "GSDContentLayer" on the Quick Help window, it takes me directly to the .h file containing the GSDContentLayer class.

Is that possible? If so, how?